# Browser Performance issues with Angular 4 app

Tags: angular

I am brand new to Angular 4 applications and have been learning about it for a few weeks.  Environment is Node v6.11.0, NPM 3.10.10, Angular CLI 1.1.3, Typescript 2.2.2.0.

I display data retrieved straight from several SQL Server tables.  I have a table with 140 columns and several thousand rows.  I recently coded a paging mechanism to get records by 1000 row blocks, and the MS WebAPI backend provides this data to the Angular app within 5 seconds or so on local dev laptop.  Last week we added a large amount of rows to the database. There was only 20 records previously and there were no performance issues with this small amount of rows.

This Angular app uses a service to get the data from SQL Server using http.get and maps it to a json array of rows from SQL Server.  Pretty basic stuff and there is no problem to this point.

Displaying large blocks of 1000 records is where performance bogs down.  This is just a simple static display with no input fields, no allowing user to edit data displayed.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:auto;" *ngFor="let column of columns">
                {{column}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{item[column]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

With 1000 record blocks, IE 11 chokes, able to grab the first 1000 records and display after 30 seconds or so, but then on next block, it just displays a blank screen and browser has to be closed.   Chrome handles it much better but there are still large delays from when data is received until it is rendered.

I found IE11 handles 50 record blocks fairly well for this particular table, but somewhere between 50 and 100 block size, IE starts to choke.  Unfortunately, our client wants to use IE and not Chrome or Firefox.

I found a few similar issues on StackOverflow but none of them had a resolution to this problem.   Can anyone suggest ways to improve performance?  I'm not sure yet how much processing Angular is doing in the background, and there should not be a need for any binding since this is a static display of data.  Does Angular have binding by default that may be causing delays to render data that can be turned off somehow?

I tried implementing "no track" but that did not make any difference in performance.

Appreciate any advice you Angular veterans can provide to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it'll improve so much .. but try to put [innerText] instead of {{}}:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:auto;" *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerText]="column">

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerText]="item[column]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And one more things ... why don't you try to `paginate` results??

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks I will give that a shot.   I have implemented pagination but client wants to use 1000 records blocks for each page.  We'll see if that's possible.  Thanks fredrico!